# .htaccess for identical url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have this url

```
http://localhost/sahara/product.php?action=viewcat
http://localhost/sahara/product.php?action=viewsubcat&catparent=40
```

and the htaccess are

```
RewriteRule product-action-(.*)\.html$ product.php?action=$1
RewriteRule product-action-(.*)-catparent-(.*)\.html$ product.php?action=$1&catparent=$2
```

Then When i Call the rewrite url, only first code are work

```
http://localhost/sahara/product-action-viewcat.html ---> it's work 
http://localhost/sahara/product-action-viewsubcat-catparent-40.html ---> it's not work
```

What is the correct code for htaccess for my script
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because the URI `/sahara/product-action-viewsubcat-catparent-40.html` also matches the **first** pattern: `product-action-(.*)\.html$`. The `(.*)` part of the regular expression, which matches *everything*, is matching the `viewsubcat-catparent-40` part of your URI.

You either need to make the expression more restrictive, or change the order of the two rules:

more restrictive (something like this):

```
RewriteRule product-action-([a-z]+)\.html$ product.php?action=$1 [L]
RewriteRule product-action-([a-z]+)-catparent-([0-9]+)\.html$ product.php?action=$1&catparent=$2 [L]
```

or just reverse the order:

```
RewriteRule product-action-(.*)-catparent-(.*)\.html$ product.php?action=$1&catparent=$2
RewriteRule product-action-(.*)\.html$ product.php?action=$1
```